# EasyNetQ want a listener to receive ALL messages

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, easynetq

I want to save EVERY message to my database.
In RabbitMQ directly I would just create a consumer to listen for topic "*" (anything) on my main/only exchange.

In EasyNetQ, it seems I have to add a line in my logging project everytime I create a new Message class. I would like to avoid this, so no matter which message I send, it will be picked up in a single place and saved to the database, for all future, without having to remember to add any lines.

I implemented my own logger

```
class MyLogger : IEasyNetQLogger
var logger = new MyLogger(); // implements IEasyNetQLogger
            _bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus(Constants.ConnString, x => x.Register<IEasyNetQLogger>(_ => logger));
```

But the parameters recieved seems to only be RoutingKey, CorrelationId, ConsumerTag, DliveryTag and Redelivered. But I (also) want the string/text message itself.

Answer (score 0):

you could work with a base class. if you define your class like this:

```
public class BaseMessage 
{
    public string Message {get; set;}
}
```

and derive every other message you create from this class. so you could do this:

```
bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus(Constants.ConnString, x => x.Register<BaseMessage>(_ => logger));
```

now you can always access to the `Message` property in your logger as long as you derive the new message from `BaseMessage`

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. In your example "logger" is expected to be a SuperMessage now, instead of a IEasyNetQLogger. Unsure how to implement a logger with the above code.

Comment: sorry, i missunterstood your question a little bit. but where do you need to add a line every time you create a new message? I can not see the message class in your posted code?